# Create React native elements with a touch event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile, touch

I need create a View element with a event touch and this touch position. Thanks for the help.

onStartShouldSetResponder={() => { createElement(element, postion) }}

Answer (score 1):

you cant touch the View component

try TouchableOpacity

TouchableOpacity · React Native - Facebook Open Source
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity